# Smooth interpolating spline has weird extremities

Tags: python, scipy, spline, smoothing, bspline

I'm building a soft to reject some trajectories that turn too fast.

I managed to smooth them with scipy splrep and splev, but I have some weirdness at the beginning and the end, with some points that does not follow at all the original trajectory.

Any idea where it comes from or how to correct it ? Can I correct it with the "weight" parameter of splrep ? I avoid this problem by analysing the trajectory without the 10 firsts and lasts points of the original one, but it's a bit annoying...

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate


pointsx = [19.96, 19.45, 18.94, 18.43, 17.92, 17.4, 17.02, 16.51, 16.0, 15.48, 14.97, 14.46, 13.95, 13.56, 13.05, 12.54, 12.03, 11.51, 11.13, 10.62, 9.98, 9.59, 9.08, 8.57, 8.06, 7.67, 7.16, 6.78, 6.27, 5.75, 5.24, 4.86, 4.35, 3.83, 3.32, 2.81, 2.43, 1.91, 1.53, 1.02, 0.51, 0.12, -0.38, -0.76, -1.28, -1.79, -2.17, -2.56, -3.07, -3.45, -3.96, -4.35, -4.86, -5.24, -5.63, -6.01, -6.4, -6.78, -7.29, -7.55, -7.93, -8.44, -8.83, -9.21, -9.59, -9.85, -10.24]
pointsy = [-13.18, -13.05, -13.05, -13.05, -13.05, -13.05, -13.18, -13.18, -13.18, -13.05, -13.05, -13.05, -13.18, -13.18, -13.18, -13.18, -13.18, -13.31, -13.31, -13.31, -13.31, -13.31, -13.31, -13.31, -13.31, -13.31, -13.43, -13.43, -13.56, -13.56, -13.56, -13.56, -13.56, -13.56, -13.69, -13.69, -13.69, -13.82, -13.82, -13.82, -13.95, -13.95, -13.95, -14.08, -14.08, -14.2, -14.2, -14.2, -14.33, -14.46, -14.46, -14.46, -14.59, -14.72, -14.72, -14.84, -14.84, -14.97, -14.97, -15.1, -15.1, -15.23, -15.35, -15.48, -15.61, -15.74, -15.87]
degree = 5
lenx = len(pointsx)
x = np.array(pointsx)
y = np.array(pointsy)
w = range(lenx)
ipl_t = np.linspace(0.0, lenx - degree, 1000)
print y.max(), y.min(), ">", abs(y.max()) - abs(y.min())
smooth = 20
x_tup, fpx, ierx, msgx = interpolate.splrep(w, x, k=degree, full_output=1) 
y_tup, fpy, iery, msgy = interpolate.splrep(w, y, k=degree, per=1,full_output=1, s=smooth, task = 0) 


x_i = interpolate.splev(ipl_t, x_tup)
y_i = interpolate.splev(ipl_t, y_tup)

fg, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1.plot(pointsx, pointsy, 'k.')
ax1.set_title("original")

ax2.plot(x_i, y_i, 'y.')
ax2.set_title("bsplined smooth=%.2f" % smooth)

ax3.plot(pointsx, pointsy, 'k',  x_i, y_i,'y')
ax3.set_title("both")

plt .show()
```

And the result : [image: trajectory]

And some others results with more relevant smoothed trajectories but with still the same gap at the end and beginning: [Trajectory2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYvsU.png)

Comment: Whenever possible, use the Stack Exchange provided hosting as described above. This ensures images are never lost. Images on on many other free image hosters will expire if not requested every now and then. Also, this is useful if your image is from an HTTP source, as images on the Stack Exchange account are from an HTTPS source (see above). The post should be useful for future visitors too.

Comment: with 1 rep, the OP does not have privileges to post an image; however, you do @uutecht, and should edit his post to render the image.

Comment: Lesson learned. Will do next time :-)

Comment: Thanks guys ! (I also tried to edit to add a Hi at the beginning but it didn't seem to work... right problem again ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpolation for y-values has parameter `per=1`. This means

> data points are considered periodic ... and a smooth periodic spline approximation is returned.

Obviously your y-values are not periodic at all, so forcing the spline to be periodic makes it deviate from the data. Removing the `per` parameter fixes the problem.

[image: per=0]

Comment: Yes I found that out, last week, I forgot to close the subject.
Thank's for the answer still !